# How is Northern Ireland currently being governed with its executive vacant and its legislature suspended?

Tags: united-kingdom, government, local-government, northern-ireland

Currently, the [Northern Ireland Executive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Ireland_Executive) is vacant while the [Northern Ireland Assembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Ireland_Assembly) is suspended, following the resignation of deputy First Minister Martin McGuinness and subsequently First Minister Arlene Foster (due to NI's power-sharing agreement).

Since both the executive and the legislative branches of Northern Ireland's devolved government are not functioning and the United Kingdom has been [unwilling to implement direct rule](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-northern-ireland-45028635), how is Northern Ireland being governed now? Who are making the decisions that should normally be made by ministers in the executive?

Comment: At a guess: It isn't. No one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Legislation is made at Westminster to provide for budgets: https://www.belfasttelegraph.co.uk/news/northern-ireland/new-government-legislation-on-northern-ireland-direct-rule-in-all-but-name-36750476.html

Operationally the civil service still report to the [Secretary of State for Northern Ireland](https://www.gov.uk/government/ministers/secretary-of-state-for-northern-ireland), who at the time of writing is Karen Bradley.

Other than that, it remains in stasis; the security services, tax office, benefits etc machinery of the state continue to operate, but no significant change will be carried out.